# Push Replacement not Working in flutter web app using go router

Tags: flutter

So i am making a web app using go router package for navigation while creating login page when user authentication is correct we normally go to homepage wont be able to come back to login page right? for that i used pushReplacement expecting not able to go back to login page but the on browsers default back arrow button on top corner i can go back.How to fix this?

i tried using `context.pushReplacement(AppRoutes.masterUser);`but as i said i can still go back login page once authenticated